# Mac terminal directory issues

Tags: macos, terminal, directory, rm

I previously had a bootcamp that I input labs in one folder but i made them all directories in my macOs terminal. I can't delete them. I tired to (rm -r) all but when I override them, they were all denied. They don't bother my ability to use terminal but its just not organized.
I tried (rm -r) but denied the first directory and said command not found for the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have write permissions on this directory. To get around this, try using the `sudo` command, which escalates your permissions. For example:

```bash
sudo rm -rf my-folder/
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. If you can tell me why that happened i would also appreciate it i dont know what i did

Comment: @MariaMarquez I don't know for sure what happened, but my guess would be that Bootcamp ran with escalated permissions (root) or under some service user other than yourself. Using `sudo` escalated that command to the highest permissions level available (the root user), which has permissions to remove the bootcamp-created user.